# Create more than one eshell instance in emacs

Tags: emacs, xmonad, eshell

Think: tiling my emacs window with eshells, a la xmonad.  Is this possible?  I can M-x eshell to open the first eshell instance but future invocations just focus the first instance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this:

```
`C-u M-x eshell`
```

This will create `*eshell*`, `*eshell*<2>`, and so on.

Answer (score 7):

My preferred approach is to create named shells:

```
(defun make-shell (name)
  "Create a shell buffer named NAME."
  (interactive "sName: ")
  (setq name (concat "$" name))
  (eshell)
  (rename-buffer name))
```

is the gist.  Then `M-x make-shell name` will create the desired shell.

Answer (score 4):

The docstring for eshell states that "A nonnumeric prefix arg means to create a new session."  I typed <kbd>M-- M-x eshell</kbd> over and over, and each time it opened a new eshell buffer.

Comment: Damn. Your comment hadn't been written when I started my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

C-u M-x eshell works great, but I prefer named shells - [make-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540997/create-more-than-one-eshell-instance-in-emacs/2541530#2541530) approach, is useful when switching buffers

Answer (score 0):

Invoking GNU Screen is another option for those using ansi-term

Answer (score 0):

Mybe, the following solution is better. Because the eshell buffer is determined by the value of eshell-buffer-name. You need not to rename the buffer.

```
(defun buffer-exists (bufname)   
  (not (eq nil (get-buffer bufname))))

(defun make-shell (name)
  "Create a shell buffer named NAME."
  (interactive "sName: ")
  (if (buffer-exists "*eshell*")
      (setq eshell-buffer-name name)
    (message "eshell doesnot exists, use the default name: *eshell*"))
  (eshell))
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [make-eshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540997/create-more-than-one-eshell-instance-in-emacs/2541530#2541530), this creates an eshell appending the next counter, so it's like *eshell1*, *eshell2*, etc.:

```
(lexical-let ((count 1))
  (defun make-eshell-next-number ()
    (interactive)
    (eshell)
    (rename-buffer (concat "*eshell" (number-to-string count) "*"))
    (setq count (1+ count))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of new eshell buffer / instance.

```
(defun eshell-new-buffer (args)
  "Create a new eshell buffer."
  (interactive "P")
  (eshell "new")
  )


(global-set-key (kbd "C-c e e") 'eshell)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c e n") 'eshell-new-buffer)
```